# Geometric Interepretation of $\mathbb{G}_a$-torsors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology

Let's fixed a locally ringed space $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ (although, this should apply to any ringed topos, but I haven't thought that through). In fact, if it's helpful, you can assume that $X$ is a complex manifold, or a scheme. The question then is:

> Is there a natural $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\mathcal{F}$ such that $\text{Aut}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{F})=\mathcal{O}_X$?

The reason for my interest is due to the fact that $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ would then classify twists of $\mathcal{F}$. For example, because $\text{Aut}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{O}_X)=\mathcal{O}_X^\times$, we know that $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X^\times)$ classifies twists of $\mathcal{O}_X$, or more colloquially, line bundles.

If there was such a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$, which had some nice geometric flavor, this might give some interesting insight into how to think about genus, or any other statistics associated to $h^1$.

I apologize if I have missed something obvious!

Thanks!

PS: I am not particularly looking for another way to think about $\mathbb{G}_a$-torsors, than the context above. For example, thinking about them as extensions via the isomorphism $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\cong \text{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ isn't particularly helpful to me, in this context.

Comment: I don't see why there would be. In the affine picture, I don't see a natural way to cook up an $R$-module with automorphism group $R$. At best, with no further hypotheses, I can cook up $R$-modules with automorphism groups $\text{GL}_n(R)$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I agree, there is no obvious way. Do you think there is actually an obstruction to such a module existing (in general)? I actually hadn't even considered that possibility--I had thought, at worst, it might just be unenlightening.

Comment: Sure. Right now I can't even think of an abelian group whose automorphism group is precisely $\mathbb{Z}$. (Note that another obstruction to there being an extremely nice answer to this question analogous to the case of line bundles is that topologically there are no interesting $\mathbb{G}_a$-torsors on reasonable spaces because $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are both contractible.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Hmm, actually now that you say that, I have doubts as well. If $\text{Aut}(G)$ is cyclic, then $G/Z(G)$ would be cyclic, so $G$ abelian, and then clearly this can't happen.

Comment: Oh, right. In the abelian case $a \mapsto -a$ is an automorphism of order $2$ unless the abelian group $A$ is an $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space, and none of these have automorphism group $\mathbb{Z}$. So there's a counterexample right there. (I guess strictly speaking this only shows that there isn't a *quasicoherent* example.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Although, truthfully, we should have been restricting to the commutative case to begin with :)

Comment: So, thinking about the trivial case where $X$ is a point, a $\mathbb{G}_a$-torsor is just an [affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space) of dimension 1. These things aren't literally modules.

Comment: @ZhenLin Could you explain a little bit more, please?

Comment: An affine space is a pair $(A, M)$ where $M$ is a module and $A$ is a set with a transitive free $M$-action (where $M$ is considered as an abelian group). If you choose a distinguished element of $A$ then you get an $M$-equivariant bijection between $A$ and $M$ (which then makes $A$ a module). But you do have to choose an element, which is non-canonical.

Comment: @ZhenLin That sounds like a principal homogenous space, correct? I don't quite know if that answers my question.

Comment: Torsor is another word for principal homogeneous space. My point is that while you can't find a _module_ with the desired automorphisms, there is something very close.

Comment: @ZhenLin Torsors and PHS aren't always the same though, for example, torsors of an algebraic group $G$ in the fppf topology needn't be equivalent to PHSs for $G$ (when you define the latter to be 'geometrically nice'). Since I, tacitly, was hoping that the above would extend to other geometric sites, I'd prefer to stick to the purely sheaf theoretic definition of torsor, and look for sheaves with the condition I stated. I appreciate the suggestion though.

Comment: The difference you speak of is superficial – it's just a question of what the ambient category is. As for sheaves – you need to expand your horizons and consider sheaves of things that are not necessarily groups or modules.

Comment: @ZhenLin I disagree with you, in so much as the category of torsors is equivalent to the category of PHSs (when you require these to be 'nice' [e.g. flat and locally of finite presentation over the base])--this is not superficial, as far as I can see. Also, of course if one moves to any setting there are many ways to understand $\mathbb{G}_a$-torsors. For example, as I said above, you can think of them as extensions. So, while I appreciate your suggestion, I'd like to know if there is an answer to my specific question. :)

Comment: Surely the answer to your original question is no, as Qiaochu explained?

Comment: @ZhenLin No, because that only discounts the quasicoherent case.

Comment: Take the spectrum of a field, say $\mathbb{F}_2$. Then there is no difference.